# Balanced mix of recent, interesting and new/unanswered posts

Tags: php, mysql, list, sorting, tagging

I'm searching algorithm, or some fitness rating method.

As an example take Stackoverflow. Posts are divided to groups by

- Rating (+,-,0)
- Tags (and tags importance based on activity in them)
- Users (user rating/reputation, age, recent activity)
- Keywords

And I'm looking for way, how to sort them to create optimized/balanced mix.
I don't want to show ONLY the newest OR ONLY the top rated OR ONLY important tags

maybe the name would be "Multiple-attributes optimal sorting", or something similar.

Anyone can advise something?
Thanks

ADD1: maybe we are talking about `Fitness function` ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate separate sub-scores for each of those factors, then normalize them, add them together, and sort by the resulting total for each post. For instance,

1. Rank all of the posts by rating, and then map their position in the ranking to a 0.0-1.0 range (highest rated post is 1.0, lowest is 0.0).
2. Create a function to take a post's tags and calculate a similar 0.0-1.0 score based on tags only.
3. Create another function to do the same for the user.
4. And another for any keywords you want.

If you want certain things to factor in more than others, multiply the subscore by a constant factor before adding it to the total - for instance, if you want rating to be important, and the others less so, you might do `(3*A)+B+C+D` if the four subscores are the letters.

As for exactly how you translate things into subscores? That's something you really have to determine for your particular app; there's no single way of doing it that is "right".

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Is there anything you can add to your answer when looking at this algorithm in scale of such big site as SO? Such as caching of subscores, or ranking each factor on SQL level?

Comment: I'd say try to store as many subscores as you can statically with their relevant data and only recalculate them when necessary. For instance, the user subscore should be stored in the users table along with all of the other user data, then just joined in. Similarly, the tag subscore should be a simple average of weights stored in the tags table. Rating subscore should be stored in the post's own row and only recalculated when a +/- vote is cast.

Comment: If you wanted, you could also cache the user subscore along with the post to avoid the joins - ranking by the weight a user had when they originally created the post isn't necessarily a bad idea (since new users might be less likely to create popular posts than proven veterans). The tags subscore can be cached and only recalculated when the post tags are edited (if ever, or even possible). Ditto for the keywords subscore, only being recalculated when the post content is edited. Thus, you can theoretically also cache the weighted total of the subscores, making it easy to run an indexed query.